# Django: what is the purpose of "$" symbol in urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django

I just lost about 1h trying to figure out why my Django routes/urls were not working for create, edit and delete. Just list was working. Here is the issue I had:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ###
    url(r'^solicitacao', views.solicitacao_list, name='solicitacao_list'),
    url(r'^solicitacao_new$', views.solicitacao_create, name='solicitacao_new'),
    url(r'^solicitacao_edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.solicitacao_update, name='solicitacao_edit'),
    url(r'^solicitacao_delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.solicitacao_delete, name='solicitacao_delete'),
]
```

The first url was missing a **$** symbol at the end, and there was no error or any message when I tried to access other urls than list

Somehow my routes got screwed up. I ended up being redirected to the list url, even though the redirect did not appear on the console. Can anybody with more django experience explain me what the $ symbol means in the routes, and why did it affect the create/edit/delete urls?

Comment: $ says that it in the endpoint of an url and can't be extended.for URL with include you should not use $ at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django urls are formed as regular expressions

$ is regex character that matches the end of the string. This matches a position, not a character.

So first match view is called, considering **all of your URLs start with solicitacao**  for each of them **first match** is list in this case

Likewise ^ is also regex character that defines start of string so in case you had url   `url(r'^asolicitacao', views.someview, name='test'),`

it would be called normally

Comment: Hum, I see ... So since I forgot to add the $ marker for the regex, the first line would end up catching any url like this "solicitacao*"? Starts with "solicitacao", and anything else after that word.

Comment: Exactly as you said